# how to remove picture from iframe - pure javascript

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to remove the logo from iframe on my website http://letenky.slehkosti.cz/

preferably I want

- **not** to use jQuery nor any other libray - only pure javascript
- make sure that the logo is **NOT** displayed at all

I tried this script in head but nothing worked. I am leaving the code as it is to show what I tried. The picture is referenced inside iframe in div `<div class="logo">` html extract is below

If I check javascript console I can see `TypeError: el is undefined` it is on line 22 which is `el.classList.remove('logo');` so the element is not found?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
el.classList.remove('logo');


});

//var el = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
//el.classList.remove('logo');


//ELEMENT.classList.remove("logo");
//div.classList.remove("logo");


//$(document).ready(function() {
//$(".header head_height_").removeClass("logo");
//});
</script>
```

This is the relevant html code

```
<div class="logo">
  <!--<a target="_blank" href="http://www.letuska.cz/?prodejce=L012003"><img src="/pp/images/main_logo_pp.png" border="0" alt="" height="100" width="350"></a> -->
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.letuska.cz">
    <img src="/pp/images/main_logo_pp.png" alt="" width="350" border="0" height="100">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the image an `<img>` tag or is it a `background-image` on `<div class="logo">`?

Comment: I updated my question with some html code. I hope it answered your question.

Comment: Actually I went on and looked at the link provided (which I don't do very often) and it looks like the `<iframe>` is within another `<iframe>` and they do not belong to the same domain as the parent page. The parent page is `letenky.slehkosti.cz` and the first `<iframe>` is `letenky-prodejci.letuska.cz` and the second level `<iframe>` is `www.letuska.cz`. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) would prohibit such access that you desire. The only way to do what you want is if you can edit both domains: `slehkosti.cz` and `letuska.cz`.

Comment: ...[Cont.] I assume that you probably don't have access to `letuska.cz` or you'd just remove the vexing logo by editing it out on the domain it is actually on.

Comment: I have only access to `letenky.slehkosti.cz` so you reckon that it cannot be done in such scenario?

Comment: No access wouldn't be possible, but you can manipulate everything around the `<iframe>` including the `<iframe>` itself. Like you could shrink the `<iframe>` to 1x1px or use `opacity` or `visibility` on it or it's parent, etc. OR the other site has an API to it's services.

Comment: which won't help me with the logo. can I overlay it with something?

Comment: @zer00ne do you want to create an answer from your comments? Then I would probably have to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

*It would be a good idea to cleanup your code to make your question more clear.*

To remove a HTML node `el` if you have a reference to it:

```
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

I cannot tell from your code if `var el = ...` selects the right element (that depends on your page contents) but the line above will certainly remove it if you are referencing it properly.

Comment: I left the code as it is on purpose. To show what I tried. The html code of the pic I want to  hide is in div `<div class="logo">`

Answer (score 0):

```
Node.prototype.rClass=function(s){
    var list = [],elem=this;
    for(var i=0;i<elem.classList.length;i++){
        if(s.indexOf(elem.classList[i]) === -1){
            list.push(elem.classList[i]);
        }
    }
    elem.className = list.join(' ').toString();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
    el.rClass(['logo']);
});
```